# Run-Time error '3075' in query expresion for SQL statement with OR conjunction

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am working on filtering SubForm records on the main Form. I am new to developing proper
SQL statements, hence the error... This is the Code so far:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
Dim sql As String
sql = "SELECT *" _
    & "FROM [Transferencias Reproductores]" _
    & "WHERE DeTanque = " & Me.Base_Número & "" _
    & " OR ATanque = " & Me.Base_Número & ""
SubformTransferencias.Form.RecordSource = sql
End Sub
```

I keep getting following error:

[image]

Here the Table used [Transferencias_Reproductores]:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Put a space  before the first word on each line - they are running together. `& " FROM"` and `& " WHERE"` - Also, if the fields are alpha characters, you need quotes - `DeTanque = '" & Me.Base_Número & "'"`

Comment: And use quotes, or better yet, parameterize your query

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It is not appropriate to add [SOLVED] to the title or edit the solution into your post. You've indicated that the problem was solved by accepting an answer. In addition, you can also upvote  that answer if you feel it was extremely helpful.

Comment: @KenWhite I am new to this site. Will not put [SOLVED] in the title anymore. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a space before the first word on each line - they are running together. Also, if the fields are alpha characters, you need quotes. Try it like this:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
Dim sql As String
sql = "SELECT *" _
    & " FROM [Transferencias Reproductores]" _
    & " WHERE DeTanque = '" & Me.Base_Número & "'" _
    & " OR ATanque = '" & Me.Base_Número & "'"
SubformTransferencias.Form.RecordSource = sql
End Sub
```

Sometimes you may find it useful to check the results of the string you built before using it. You can view it using the immediate window:

```
Debug.Print sql
Stop
```

Then you can check to make sure it looks right, or you can even paste that result into Access itself (as a query) to see if it gives you more information about the error you are getting.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you very much